# MathJax and Markdown

Tags: markdown, mathjax

I write the markdown code:

```
`$$ math formula $$`
```

And I want to display `$$ math formula $$`, but mathjax parse $$ to `{% math %}`, so it displays `{% math %} math formula {% endmath %}`. I can't find solution.

Comment: Hmm since there are different markdown flavours it's hard to answer without some further details (like editor etc.).

Comment: Oh, I use the gitbook.

Comment: Hmm, okay. According to this [site](https://www.gitbook.com/blog/features/katex) you can also use KaTeX instead of MathJax for math mode. However, I also encounter some issues with MathJax at the moment (using Atom and Markdown Preview Plus). Maybe they're having service issues or so ...

Comment: Oh, the result of katex is the same as mathjax.

Comment: Hmm, interesting. I just hope that the code you posted (`'$$ math formula $$ '`) is just a typo. Because if you put math into a code block issues like those you describe sound reasonable (I get slightly different ones with my editor however the result is similar -> no math formula).

However, something appears to be wrong with GitBooks parsing. Since the `{% math % }` thing appears to be the "correct" math format for GitBook  (see [here](https://github.com/GitbookIO/plugin-mathjax)).

Comment: Yeah, I put '$$ math formula $$' in code quote, so I don't want mathjax to parse $$, but $$ is parsed by mathjax.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141285/discussion-between-gauss-and-marco-n).